# Addresses in distribution list in the Global Address Book of a non-default account

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using MS Office 2010.

My Outlook is configured with two email IDs. One is client another one is company.

I have a code in Excel to check an Outlook distribution list and import member details into Excel.

I am able to import the details from a distribution list in the GAL for a default mail ID.

I am unable to select the distribution list in the GAL for other email.

It searches for the DL in the default account's GAL and selects the wrong name.

```vb
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application  
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace  
Dim olAL As Outlook.AddressList  
Dim olEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry  
Dim olMember As Outlook.AddressEntry  
Dim lMemberCount As Long  
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem  
   
Set olApp = Outlook.Application  
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
Set olAL = olNS.AddressLists("Global Address List")  
 
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
   
' enter the list name  
Set olEntry = olAL.AddressEntries(".DL IS Support")  
   
' get count of dist list members  
lMemberCount = olEntry.Members.Count
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to get the GAL container from another Exchange account in your profile?

Comment: yes, while searching, always it is searching from one GAL not from the other. To check on other GAL where and what i have to modify in my above code.